# unable to use google Oauth with Azure mobile services in android app

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to add authentication for android app using azure mobile services and its authentication providers.I am using mobile services 1.1.5 jar and my android project targets API 19.

> The method login(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider, JsonObject,
>   UserAuthenticationCallback) is ambiguous for the type
>   MobileServiceClient

Here is my code

```
private void authenticate() { // Login using the Google provider.

    ListenableFuture<MobileServiceUser> mLogin = mClient.login(null, null, null);

    Futures.addCallback(mLogin, new FutureCallback<MobileServiceUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable exc) {
            createAndShowDialog((Exception) exc, "Error");
        }           
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(MobileServiceUser user) {
            createAndShowDialog(String.format(
                    "You are now logged in - %1$2s",
                    user.getUserId()), "Success");
            createTable();  
        }
    });     

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ListenableFuture overloads are not available in SDK 1.1.5. You will need the version 2.0.1 beta SDK. An overview and a link to download this version are available on the [Azure team blog](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/04/futures-support-and-breaking-changes-in-azure-mobile-services-android-sdk/).

In addition, the new overload for login() does not take three parameters. You will need to pass in a provider, which can be either a string or a MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider object. Optionally you can also pass a token, which is either a string or a JsonObject.

If your goal is to use Google authentication, I would expect you would call the following:

```
ListenableFuture<MobileServiceUser> mLogin = mClient.login("google");
```

If it's useful, the [source for the beta SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/android/sdk/android/src/sdk/src/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/MobileServiceClient.java) is available.

Alternatively, you can continue to use the 1.1.5 SDK, but you may need to provide a [UserAuthenticationCallback](http://dl.windowsazure.com/androiddocs/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/UserAuthenticationCallback.html) object if you wish to take action on the result. This would be an additional optional parameter to login().